# F# pattern matching

Tags: .net, f#, pattern-matching

I'm puzzled by how pattern matching works in F# for `let`. I'm using the Visual Studio 'F# interactive' window, F# version 1.9.7.8. Say we define a simple type:

```
type Point = Point of int * int ;;
```

and the try to pattern match against values of `Point` using `let`.

```
let Point(x, y) = Point(1, 2) in x ;;
```

fails with `error FS0039: The value or constructor 'x' is not defined`. How is one supposed to use  pattern matching with `let`?

The most curious thing is that:

```
let Point(x, y) as z = Point(1, 2) in x ;;
```

returns 1 as expected. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis around your pattern:

```
let (Point(x, y)) = Point(1, 2) in x ;;
```

Otherwise there's no way to distinguish the pattern from a function-binding...